# Nginx Configuration - Passing route to index.php on a very custom setup

Tags: php, nginx, system-administration

Something tells me that, the way I went about this from the start is wrong, which is making it difficult for me to solve this new problem... But here we go!

### The Setup

```
    location ~ ^/dev/([^\/]+?)\/(.*) {
            alias /opt/dev/$1/www/$2;
            autoindex on;

            # PHP location check for personal dev environments
            location ~ ^/dev/([^\/]+?)\/([^\/].+\/|)(.+\.php)$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$3;
                    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE error_log=/opt/dev/$1/logs/php_errors.log;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            }
    }
```

This setup above allows my devs to each have their own personal development environment.  Going to: http://site_url/dev/[user]/[project]/ works just fine, if there are php files in that project directory, which locally would be in **/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/** directory. This alone took me quite a bit of time to figure out, but now we have a new dillema that has been kicking my ass for 8 straight hours now.

*Note: Regex is my weakness in programming, so the fact that nginx configuration for such things are regex based is killing me sofly*

### The Problem

I need to be able to detect when a path beyond the [project] level is unreachable, and then redirect that request to index.php on the project level, WITH a route param, so that we can handle it on the php level.

For example:

http://site_url/dev/[user]/[project]/something/else/

If the directory **/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/something/else** does not exist (or there's no php files in it), I need the request to go to **/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/index.php**, but also I want to call index.php with a "route" param that gives the rest of the url.

(i.e: index.php?route=something/else )

I hope this makes sense and i reeeeeeally hope someone can help me here.
I acknowledge that this might mean changing my config entirely, but I don't care as long as it works.

### Full Source

This is my whole entire config file from top to bottom:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 192.168.20.200;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/dev/([^\/]+?)\/(.*) {
            alias /opt/dev/$1/www/$2;
            autoindex on;

            # PHP location check for personal dev environments
            location ~ ^/dev/([^\/]+?)\/([^\/].+\/|)(.+\.php)$ {                
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$3;
                    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE error_log=/opt/dev/$1/logs/php_errors.log;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are trying to do is `try_files` Serve the file if it exists, try the next if it doesn't. Something like this should work, I'm using a third regex block to capture your route variable, which I'm passing in the headers.

```
location ~ ^/dev/(\w+)\/((?1))(.*) {
    root /opt;
    autoindex on;
    add_header x-route $3;
    try_files  /dev/$1/www/$2$3/index.php /dev/$1/www/$2$3.php /dev/$1/www/$2$3/ /dev/$1/www/$2/index.php =404;
```

Nginx will now try and process your request for /dev/[user]/www/[project]/something/else like this:

First try `/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/something/else/index.php`

Next try `/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/something/else.php`

Next try and show the index of `/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/something/else/`

Next try and fall back to `/opt/dev/[user]/www/[project]/index.php` In your PHP script the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ROUTE']` will be '/something/else'

Finally, if none of those work return 404.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the detailed response.. I'll give it a shot tomorrow.